# Rails 7 with Devise and token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I have a rails 7 app with devise in development mode.
When i register a new user, the token response is encrypted in the terminal and i can't recreate the link to confirm the user account.

How is it possible to acquire the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.send_confirmation_instructions` method. Probably you need to configure a tool like "Letter opener" to read this email in development.

Comment: thank you!
I installed the letter_opener gem and followed the instructions and problem solved for development mode.